# Quando clicar na div menor, abrir na maior

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte layout.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O quadrado maior, mostra um dos quadrados menores, só que em tamanho maior. Ou seja, se eu clicar no segundo quadrado menor, ele tem que mostrar no quadrado maior.

Existe algum plugin para isso? Pois preciso que seja gerenciável.

Comment: O que abriria na div maior? Uma imagem maior que na div menor?

Comment: Tipo, são 3 imagens, conforme os quadrados menores. Quando eu clicar no quadrado menor 2, por exemplo, ele vai abrir a imagem que tem nesse quadrado no quadrado maior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A estrutura é bem simples. Temos a seguinte marcação HTML:

```
<div id="big"><img src="" /></div>
<ul>
    <li><img src="exemplo.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="exemplo.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="exemplo.png" /></li>
</ul>
```

Sua marcação pode ser diferente dessa, mas o que importa é a mecânica. O objetivo é mostrar a imagem clicada na div maior, certo? Vamos começar criando a função para ser rodada ao clicar em alguma das imagens:

```
$('ul li img').click(function() {...
```

Primeiro pegamos a url da imagem que foi clicada:

```
var url = $(this).attr('src');
```

E então definimos a nova url da imagem da div `#big`:

```
$('#big img').attr('src', url);
```

Simples, não é mesmo?

---

### Demonstração

O CSS é só para melhorar a apresentação mesmo.

```js
$(function() {
    $('ul li img').click(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('src');
        $('#big img').attr('src', url);
    });
});
```

```css
#big {
    border:1px solid #333;
    width:300px;
    height:250px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

ul {
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0;
}

ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

img {
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="big"><img src="" /></div>
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://static.hsw.com.br/gif/gatos-2.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.mensagenscomamor.com/images/interna/new/frases_de_gatos.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8608/16526776600_7acef45936_o.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Resposta excelente. Poderia funcionar assim também? https://jsfiddle.net/p25pofpv/

Comment: Se estiver falando dos caminhos relativos, desde que estejam corretos, sim.

Comment: E estão, estranho é que não funcionou quando eu cliquei.

Comment: No JS Fiddle ou no projeto?

Comment: Consegui, valeu! :D

Comment: Você tinha esquecido de colocar o jQuery no Fiddle. De nada, sempre que precisar estamos ai :)